# Daisy chain Thunderbolt display to regular, fullsize DisplayPort monitor?

Tags: display, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I have a 27" Korean IPS with a full size DisplayPort input (not Thunderbolt). Is it possible to drive this monitor daisy chained off a 27" Apple Thunderbolt monitor, using a mini DisplayPort output to fullsize DisplayPort cable? The Apple monitor would be driven by my late 2011 MacBook Pro.

Couldn't find a clear answer on this, as I think people are confusing DisplayPort and Thunderbolt quite a bit. My guess is you **can't** do this, because perhaps you can only daisy chain a thunderbolt monitor to another thunderbolt monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [Thunderbolt Ports and Displays FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#minimul):

> #### Can I connect a Mini DisplayPort display to my Apple Thunderbolt Display for computers that support using more than one display?
>
> Mini DisplayPort displays will not function if connected to the Thunderbolt port of an Apple Thunderbolt Display. Displays connected via Mini DisplayPort video adapter or cable to the Thunderbolt port of an Apple Thunderbolt Display will not work.

So as you guessed, you can't daisychain a non-Thunderbolt display to a Thunderbolt display. You can only do it with two Thunderbolt displays (or of course, two displays on different ports directly connected to your Mac).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I was a little confused because the other monitor is not a Mini DisplayPort monitor, but the cable would have to be an mDP to fit the Apple, so this answers it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. There's no difference between mini-Displayport and Displayport in terms of compatibility, it's simply a different sized plug.